# There is inconsistency in connection from Android phone to Windows 7 64 bit PC

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, windows

There are problems transferring files between my laptop and my phone. The symptoms I encountered are strange and I hope for a comprehensive explanation and solution to the problem

### Background:

- Computer Windows 7 64 Bit
- Phone Android 4.0.3
- Drivers are all up to date, using Windows Device Manager.
- Both devices successfully paired.
- Bluetooth is on.

I will describe the steps of my experience in sending and receiving below.

### Sending file from computer to phone

#### Method 1

1. Right clicked "Bluetooth Devices" icon in system tray
2. Clicked on "Show Bluetooth Devices"
3. Right clicked on Bluetooth Device (my only Bluetooth Device)
4. Clicked "Control" → "Send files to phone"
5. Clicked "Browse Files..." → Chose my file → Clicked "Send"
6. Sending Dialog popped up
7. On my phone, was asked to authenticate, clicked yes
8. Sending complete.

In the above steps, sending is SUCCESSFUL.

#### Method 2

1. Right clicked on the exact same file I successfully sent above
2. Click "Send to → Bluetooth"
3. Bluetooth Send Wizard pops up
4. Clicked "Next" → Selected Bluetooth Device → Clicked "OK"
5. Displayed Error `Bluetooth device not found. Please verify that your Bluetooth device is properly connected and turned on`.

In these steps. sending is NOT successful. Please help me identify why.

### Next, I will move on to sending file from phone to computer:

#### Method 1

Using the exact same file on phone, tapped "Send via Bluetooth" → On the phone displayed `Bluetooth share: Sent 1 failed`. On the computer nothing happened, no notifications at all.

In these steps, sending is NOT successful.

#### Method 2

1. Clicked Start button → Typed "fsquirt" in Run
2. Bluetooth File Transfer dialog popped up → Clicked "Receive files"
3. Displayed `Waiting for connection`
4. On phone, tapped the same "Send via Bluetooth" → Bluetooth File Transfer on computer shows sending progress → Sending complete.

In the above steps. sending is SUCCESSFUL.

### Question:

Can someone explain to me the discrepancies in my experience in sending and receiving between the computer and phone? The 2 devices are obviously connected and sending is possible, so why does 1 method work while another does not? What happened?

Edit:
I shall refer to the above sending and receiving methods as Sending 1, Sending 2, Receiving 1 and Receiving 2.

When 'Control' dialog box with the "Send files to phone" option is opened,

- Sending 2 becomes SUCCESSFUL
- Receiving 2 becomes NOT successful.